# Проблема с автосвойствами. Ошибка компилятора CS0840

Tags: c#, компилятор

Я использую VS 2012

> error CS0840: Pisos.Rectangle.Area.get должен декларировать тело, так
>   как оно не отмечено как абстрактное или внешнее. Автоматически
>   реализованные свойства должны определять функции доступа get и set.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 20);
        double a = rectangle.AreaCalc(rectangle.side1, rectangle.side2);
        double b = rectangle.PerimeterCalc(rectangle.side1, rectangle.side2);

        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Rectangle
{
    public double side1, side2;

    public Rectangle(double side1, double side2)
    {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
    }

    double Area { get; }
    double Perimeter { get; }

    public double AreaCalc(double side1, double side2)
    {
        double Ar = side1 * side2;
        return Ar;
    }

    public double PerimeterCalc(double side1, double side2)
    {
        double Per = 2 * (side1 + side2);
        return Per;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарий к ошибке:
error CS0840: Pisos.Rectangle.Area.get должен декларировать тело, так как оно не отмечено как абстрактное или внешнее. Автоматически реализованные свойства должны определять функции доступа get и set.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить вопрос, воспользуйтесь ссылкой "править" под вопросом.

Comment: Какую версию VS/компилятора используете?

Comment: Я использую VS 2012

Comment: Маленькое замечание по коду, в методах AreaCalc и PerimeterCalc можно не создавать переменную для возвращающего значения возвращать сразу результат выражения. Например:
 return side1 * side2;

Comment: И в данном случае не очень понятно использование свойств, т.к. они нигде не используются.

Comment: @V.Birkos насчет "лишней" переменной спорно. Я, например, всегда ввожу переменную, если возвращается результат какого-то вычисления, которое нельзя быстро сделать в уме. Это полезно при отладке, чтобы увидеть, какое значение возвращает метод.

Comment: @andreycha Согласен, момент спорный и зависит от конкретной ситуации, по этому я и написал "можно" в своем комментарии. Т.к. мне показалось, что в данном случае все же лучше убрать переменные.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

В C# версии младше 6 автосвойства только для чтения (содержат только `get`) не поддерживаются. Варианта два:

1. Используйте VS 2015 (в ней используется компилятор для C# 6).
2. Добавьте `private set`. Это более правильный вариант, учитывая, что, судя по коду, эти свойства не являются readonly свойствами.